# How to avoid same posts in all pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom loop for exclusion of sticky post from the flow. So in that loop no sticky post came, but the problem is when I went to `page/2/` or `page/3/` same posts are repeating.

```html
<?php 

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $rest = new WP_Query(array(      
    'post__not_in'          => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'paged'                 => $paged,
    
));
?>

<?php if($rest->have_posts()) { ?>
    <?php while($rest->have_posts()) { ?>
        <?php $rest->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('template/main/main-content'); ?>
       
        
    <?php }  ?>
    
<?php } else { ?>
        <p> no post available </p>
<?php } ?>

<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Is this in a page template you have assigned as your static front page? If so, you need to use `page`, not `paged`, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: it is not a static page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many attempts and finally I cracked the code.
I just add

```html
wp_reset_query();
```

in the second line from top.... just after opening tag of php and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this parameter in your argument : 'posts_per_page'. It will call the next records according to the page number you pass.

Comment: No, It was not needed.